# Erlang Code understanding

Tags: erlang, concurrent-programming

Hi I am doing some Erlang training by understanding some basic Erlang server modules. However I am getting stuck on this one. In this module I am supposed to tell the lowest and highest possible values that can be printed by each of the 3 processes (parent and 2 child processes) because depending on particular order of execution, different values may get printed by the 3 processes.

I executed the test and got 2 for Parent, 3 for both of the child processes but I don't know how they got those values. Can someone specifically explain the process to me? Appreciated.

Here is the module:

```html
-module(p4).
-export([start/0, init/0, read/1, incr/1, reset/1, test/0]).

start()->
    spawn(fun() -> init() end).
init() -> loop(0).

loop(N) ->
    receive
   {read, Pid} ->
     Pid ! {value, self(), N},
     loop(N);
 {incr, Pid} ->
            Pid ! {incr_reply, self()},
     loop(N+1);
 {reset, Pid} ->
            Pid ! {reset_reply, self()},    
     loop(0)
   end.

read(Serv) ->
    Serv ! {read, self()},
    receive {value, Serv, N} -> N end.

incr(Serv)->
    Serv ! {incr, self()},
    receive{incr_reply, Serv} -> ok end.

reset(Serv) ->
    Serv ! {reset, self()},
    receive {reset_reply, Serv} -> ok end.
     
test() ->    
    Server = start(),
    spawn(fun() -> incr(Server),
     io:format("Child 1 read ~p~n", [read(Server)]) end),
    incr(Server),
    spawn(fun() -> incr(Server),
            io:format("child 2 read ~p~n", [read(Server)]) end),
    io:format("Parent read ~p~n", [read(Server)]).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print any message server is receiving (or use debugger tracing) for better understanding and you should get something like:

```
Server state was: 0 and received: {incr,<0.59.0>}
Server state was: 1 and received: {incr,<0.109.0>}
Server state was: 2 and received: {read,<0.59.0>}
Server state was: 2 and received: {incr,<0.110.0>}
Parent read 2
Server state was: 3 and received: {read,<0.109.0>}
Server state was: 3 and received: {read,<0.110.0>}
Child 1 read 3
child 2 read 3
```

`<0.59.0>` is parent process, `<0.109.0>` is child 1 and `<0.110.0>` is child 2.

It means that parent `read` message was delivered before `read` of children processes but after first child `incr`. But it doesn't have to be like this. It depends on process scheduling. The only guarantee you have is that messages sent from process A to process B will be delivered in the same order. 
Due to synchronous nature of `incr(Server)` and `read(Server)` it doesn't really matter.  Because each of these processes runs `incr(Server)` before `read(Server)` it must get at least 1 but note that child 2 was spawned after parent executed `incr(Server)` which is synchronous operation so it must be at least 1 when it runs its own `incr(Server)`, so when it reads it must be at least 2. The maximum value for each of them is 3 (overall number of `incr(Server)` and means that any `read(Server)` of each of them may be delayed).

Summary of possible printed values: Parent: 1,2,3; Child 1: 1,2,3; Child 2: 2,3

Simplified execution order of:

your case (parent gets 2 and both children get 3):

```
parent: spawn server
parent: spawn child 1
parent: incr(Server)
child 1: incr(Server)
parent: spawn child 2
parent: io:format("parent read ~p~n",[read(Server)]) % prints 2
child 2: incr(Server)
child 1: parent: io:format("child 1 read ~p~n",[read(Server)]) % prints 3
child 2: parent: io:format("child 2 read ~p~n",[read(Server)]) % prints 3
```

minimum case for child 1:

```
parent: spawn server
parent: spawn child 1
child 1: incr(Server)
child 1: io:format("child 1 read ~p~n",[read(Server)]) % prints 1
...
```

maximum case for parent:

```
parent: spawn server
parent: spawn child 1
parent: incr(Server)
parent: spawned child 2
child 1: incr(Server)
child 2: incr(Server)
Parent: io:format("child 1 read ~p~n",[read(Server)]) % prints 3
...
```

I've created massive test which spawned 100000 processes which run `test/0` simultaneously and created external `stat_server` which gets and counts every process `read(Server)` resault and here it is:

```
[{{child1,1},2}, % child 1 reads 1 only twice. Sometimes it's 1 sometimes it's 0, it varies
 {{child1,2},53629},
 {{child1,3},46369},
 {{child2,2},107},
 {{child2,3},99893},
 {{parent,1},855},
 {{parent,2},99112},
 {{parent,3},33}]
```

Comment: Can you tell me which lines specify that message B sended after message A from the same process is going to be delivered to the destination process after A?  And also why each of these processes is sending `incr` before `read`?

Comment: @user1579701 Every process runs incr(Server) before read(Server). Look at definition of read/1. Spawn function is only creating new process. It doesn't wait until it's done or started passed function execution.

Comment: @user1579701 just noticed my mistake in case of minimum value for read of child 2. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One precision to understand Lukasz's answer is that all Server interfaces (read,incr, reset) are synchronous: they wait for an answer from the server. This means that the process which uses these interfaces cannot do anything until the Server completes the request. It is very important to justify that child2 cannot read less than 2.

2 sequence diagrams to visualize the processes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So in case `incr(Server)` was only sending message without waiting for acknowledge then it is possible for child 2 to read 1 also? I modified code a bit (deleted child 1 to increase chance) and run many massive tests with millions of processes and child 2 never did read 1. I can't find any simple description of implementation of message passing but from my understanding of source code (poor really) of message passing and message queue, child 2 can't read 1 anyway. But it is just an implementation not a paradigm, right?

Comment: I guess that if the core running the server is busy with other stuff, the different messages may be waiting to be handled all together by this core (it is a guess, I don't know how it is implemented in the different versions of the beam machine). Then it is possible that the incr and read messages of child2 are taken first. At least there is no guarantee that it will never happen.